# can I capture invalid request info with apim event hubs?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

APIM Event Hubs are recommended for logging through APIM.  Do you know if this approach can capture invalid request info?  I know that invalid request info can be captured through Azure Diagnostics but I'm wondering if I can capture this information through an EventHubs-only solution or if I'll need to implement an additional solution through Azure Diagnostics to capture invalid request info?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely capture failed requests via Event Hubs.

There are two cases you will need to handle.  The first is if the backend Web API (aka Origin Server) returns a 400 class and/or 500 class error.  In this case you can simply inspect the response status code in the in the `Outbound` policy and log if for the desired status codes.  It will be similar to how I do [Slack notifications on failed requests](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-sample-send-request/)

For exceptions that occur in the API management gateway, either due to failure to connect to the origin server, or because some policy fails because it is missing necessary data, you can use the [on-error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/mt629506.aspx) policy.

In both cases you can construct a message that you can then [send to Event hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-log-to-eventhub-sample/)